# Animate marker to new location like uber car animation whenever driver location (lat lng) changes on the server

Tags: android, animation

```
private void GetDriverloc(HashMap<String, String> map) {
    Call<DriverLocationResToCus> call = apiInterface.GetDriverLoc(map);
    System.out.println("enter the currency alert api" + call.request().url());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<DriverLocationResToCus>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DriverLocationResToCus> call, Response<DriverLocationResToCus> response) {


            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                assert response.body() != null;
                DriverStartLat = response.body().getDriverCurrentLatStart();
                DriverStartLng = response.body().getDriverCurrentLngStart();
                DriverEndLat = response.body().getDriverCurrentLatEnd();
                DriverEndLng = response.body().getDriverCurrentLngEnd();
```

/here I am getting the driver's location from server. I need to pass the driver lat lnt to the loop and animate the marker accordingly. I tried to pass it directly to the startpostion and endpostion. But the marker flickers continuesly.

```
                Utilities.printV("DriverStartLat", DriverStartLat);

                ValueAnimator polylineAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 100);
                polylineAnimator.setDuration(2000);
                polylineAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                polylineAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                        List<LatLng> points = greyPolyLine.getPoints();
                        int percentValue = (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                        int size = points.size();
                        int newPoints = (int) (size * (percentValue / 100.0f));
                        List<LatLng> p = points.subList(0, newPoints);
                        blackPolyline.setPoints(p);
                    }
                });
                polylineAnimator.start();



                    mHandler = new Handler();
                    index = -1;
                    next = 1;
                    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        if (index < points.size() - 1) {
                            index++;
                            next = index + 1;
                        }
                        if (index < points.size() - 1) {
                            startPosition = points.get(index);
                            endPosition = points.get(next);
                        }
```

//when I pass the driver's lat lng directly to the startposition and endposition the marker moves to the new location but it comes back if it does not get new lat lat from the server and also flickers continuously.

```
                            ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
                            valueAnimator.setDuration(3000);
                            valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                            valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                                    v = valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
                                    lng = v * endPosition.longitude + (1 - v)
                                            * startPosition.longitude;
                                    lat = v * endPosition.latitude + (1 - v)
                                            * startPosition.latitude;

                                    LatLng newPos = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                                    marker.setPosition(newPos);
                                    marker.setAnchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
                                    marker.setRotation(getBearing(startPosition, newPos));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                .newCameraPosition
                                        (new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                                .target(newPos)
                                                .zoom(15.5f)
                                                .build()));
                                }
                            });
                            valueAnimator.start();
                            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
                        }
                    }, 3000);

                Utilities.printV("DriverLocationResToCus", "DriverLocationResToCus SUCCESS");


            } else {

                Utilities.printV("DriverLocationResToCus", "DriverLocationResToCus FAILURE");
                
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<DriverLocationResToCus> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}
```

//can anyone help me with this pls

Comment: I got it. :) ...

Comment: how @aravind can you explain

Comment: If you want, I can share my code @M.Yogeshwaran

Comment: please do @Aravind

Comment: MarkerAnimation.animateMarkerToGB(marker, endPosition, new LatLngInterpolator.Spherical());
                        @M.Yogeshwaran

Comment: share you full code snippet here

Comment: You can download MarkerAnimation and LatLngInterpolator files from the below links (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i-pDZYOtf-Vl8m6wnYulGnv3rb9aVMih)

Comment: (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AypW3b6YIX6UtYFFuh1-lx7Id1lt0QqP)

Comment: Let me Know if there is any error@M.Yogeshwaran

Comment: You just need to pass the user Lat Lng in endPosition to animate marker and you if you want to rotate the icon, add the below code (marker.setRotation(getBearing(endPosition, startPosition));)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download MarkerAnimation and LatLngInterpolator files from the below links

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i-pDZYOtf-Vl8m6wnYulGnv3rb9aVMih/view
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AypW3b6YIX6UtYFFuh1-lx7Id1lt0QqP/view

or Use the below posted code

MarkerAnimation code:

```
public class MarkerAnimation {
public static void animateMarkerToGB(final Marker marker, final LatLng finalPosition, final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator) {
    final LatLng startPosition = marker.getPosition();
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final Interpolator interpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
    final float durationInMs = 3000;

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        long elapsed;
        float t;
        float v;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Calculate progress using interpolator
            elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            t = elapsed / durationInMs;
            v = interpolator.getInterpolation(t);

            marker.setPosition(latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, finalPosition));

            // Repeat till progress is complete.
            if (t < 1) {
                // Post again 16ms later.
                handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
            }
        }
    });
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
static void animateMarkerToHC(final Marker marker, final LatLng finalPosition, final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator) {
    final LatLng startPosition = marker.getPosition();

    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float v = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
            LatLng newPosition = latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, finalPosition);
            marker.setPosition(newPosition);
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.setFloatValues(0, 1); // Ignored.
    valueAnimator.setDuration(3000);
    valueAnimator.start();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
public static void animateMarkerToICS(Marker marker, LatLng finalPosition, final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator) {
    TypeEvaluator<LatLng> typeEvaluator = new TypeEvaluator<LatLng>() {
        @Override
        public LatLng evaluate(float fraction, LatLng startValue, LatLng endValue) {
            return latLngInterpolator.interpolate(fraction, startValue, endValue);
        }
    };
    Property<Marker, LatLng> property = Property.of(Marker.class, LatLng.class, "position");
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(marker, property, typeEvaluator, finalPosition);
    animator.setDuration(3000);
    animator.start();
}
```

}

LatLngInterpolator Code :

```
public interface LatLngInterpolator {
public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b);

public class Linear implements LatLngInterpolator {
    @Override
    public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b) {
        double lat = (b.latitude - a.latitude) * fraction + a.latitude;
        double lng = (b.longitude - a.longitude) * fraction + a.longitude;
        return new LatLng(lat, lng);
    }
}

public class LinearFixed implements LatLngInterpolator {
    @Override
    public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b) {
        double lat = (b.latitude - a.latitude) * fraction + a.latitude;
        double lngDelta = b.longitude - a.longitude;

        // Take the shortest path across the 180th meridian.
        if (Math.abs(lngDelta) > 180) {
            lngDelta -= Math.signum(lngDelta) * 360;
        }
        double lng = lngDelta * fraction + a.longitude;
        return new LatLng(lat, lng);
    }
}

public class Spherical implements LatLngInterpolator {

    /* From github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils */
    @Override
    public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng from, LatLng to) {
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp
        double fromLat = toRadians(from.latitude);
        double fromLng = toRadians(from.longitude);
        double toLat = toRadians(to.latitude);
        double toLng = toRadians(to.longitude);
        double cosFromLat = cos(fromLat);
        double cosToLat = cos(toLat);

        // Computes Spherical interpolation coefficients.
        double angle = computeAngleBetween(fromLat, fromLng, toLat, toLng);
        double sinAngle = sin(angle);
        if (sinAngle < 1E-6) {
            return from;
        }
        double a = sin((1 - fraction) * angle) / sinAngle;
        double b = sin(fraction * angle) / sinAngle;

        // Converts from polar to vector and interpolate.
        double x = a * cosFromLat * cos(fromLng) + b * cosToLat * cos(toLng);
        double y = a * cosFromLat * sin(fromLng) + b * cosToLat * sin(toLng);
        double z = a * sin(fromLat) + b * sin(toLat);

        // Converts interpolated vector back to polar.
        double lat = atan2(z, sqrt(x * x + y * y));
        double lng = atan2(y, x);
        return new LatLng(toDegrees(lat), toDegrees(lng));
    }

    private double computeAngleBetween(double fromLat, double fromLng, double toLat, double toLng) {
        // Haversine's formula
        double dLat = fromLat - toLat;
        double dLng = fromLng - toLng;
        return 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin(dLat / 2), 2) +
                cos(fromLat) * cos(toLat) * pow(sin(dLng / 2), 2)));
    }
}
```

}

This is the bit of code that rotates the icon(marker) on the map

```
private float getBearing(LatLng begin, LatLng end) {
double lat = Math.abs(begin.latitude - end.latitude);
double lng = Math.abs(begin.longitude - end.longitude);

if (begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
    return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)));
else if (begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
    return (float) ((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 90);
else if (begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
    return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)) + 180);
else if (begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
    return (float) ((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 270);
return -1;
```

}

This is the bit of code that you need to add after getting Lat and Lng from api.

```
if(marker == null) { 
                    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(endPosition)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE)));
                    MarkerAnimation.animateMarkerToGB(marker, endPosition, new LatLngInterpolator.Spherical());
                    marker.setRotation(getBearing(endPosition, startPosition));

                } else {
                    MarkerAnimation.animateMarkerToICS(marker, endPosition, new LatLngInterpolator.Spherical());
                    marker.setRotation(getBearing(endPosition, startPosition));

                }
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Don't write code only answers. Please go ahead and add an explaination.